# Catch socket.io server down error

Tags: node.js, socket.io

How do I handle a socket.io client when the socket.io server is unavailable? Currently when the socket.io server is unavailable the client site is also unavailable. Is there a way to use try/catch to handle situations where the server is not available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [doc](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/#manager(url:string,-opts:object)), there are events for `connect_error`, `connect_timeout`, `reconnect_error` and `reconnect_failed`.  If you listen to all these error messages you will see when the client is unable to connect to the server.

socket.io does not throw exceptions for connection issues because they are all async issues so they need to be communicated back via messages/events.